# A constrained André's reflection principle

Tags: combinatorics

The question is to find a bijection between

(a) lattice paths from (0, 0) to (n, n) with exactly k "up"
steps below the line y = x,

(b) lattice paths from (0, 0) to (n, n) that never go below the line y = x.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I agree with @José Carlos Santos. Your question is classical : it is called  **André's reflection principle** for Bertrand's ballot problem. Besides, for the pleasure of eyes, and more, don't miss (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/lectures/Cat/pakcat.htm)

Comment: ... thus I have taken the liberty to change your title.

Comment: But here you have a constraint on the number of "up" steps.

Comment: Specifically, you want the third proof in the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Third_proof